# How to use public key authentication to login a ssh-server on WINDOWS?

Tags: windows, powershell, ssh

I'm trying to login to my desktop's WSL from my laptop. I have installed the ssh-server (sshd) service (on Windows 10) and I was testing it. I successfully login the ssh with password by `ssh <username>@localhost`. Then I tried to get rid of the password and failed. When I enable both of password and pubkey authentication, password is always required.

When I just enable pubkey authentication, I got `<username>@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).`.
I find the log in Event Viewer: `sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user <username> 127.0.0.1 port 9931 [preauth]`.

I have tried to use `ssh -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub <username>@localhost` to ensure the public key is correctly read by ssh client.
I have tried to generate `authorized_keys` by the command from [Key-based authentication in OpenSSH for Windows: User key generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_keymanagement). But I still cannot confirm whether the `authorized_keys` file is correctly configed. (I know that my problem may be solved by `chmod 700` in Linux, but I have no idea about Windows)

Answer (score 1):

I just solved the problem after I checked `sshd_config` again and agian. I hope this problem doesn't waste more people's time so I opened this question.

It's a stupid problem. The solution is just delete the last 2 lines in `sshd_config`:

```
Match Group administrators
   AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

I did not find any description of this configuration from [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration) because it just gives link of [original manual](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config) and the configuration is unique to Windows.

The problem is [asked on Github](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/issues/1948) but it is not fixed.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to fix the problem without editing **c:\ProgramData\ssh\sshd_config** by copying the content of public key "**./ssh/id_rsa.pub**" to file **c:\ProgramData\ssh\administrators_authorized_keys**
you can create it if it does not exist.
And you can force your system to use the public key when login by adding

```
Host remote_server_ip
    HostName remote_server_ip
    User remote_user_name
    ForwardAgent yes
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

to the local system file "**~/.ssh/config**"
you can create it if it does not exist.